# what's the utility of json with grails?

Tags: json, grails

I've read many tutorials showing how to use json with grails using templates, but what the utility of doing so? why would I want to show plain json page? ? what the utility of json templates ?   like :  (from grails official documentation)

```
model {
    Person person
}
json {
    name person.name
    age person.age
}
```

since they're not allowing ANY styling ?
Thank you

Comment: Think from "producing" a REST API standpoint, you will get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still can't get the "REST API" architecture meaning, I thought that it means simply using the methods PUT POST DELETE ... but after reading several docs it seems that I was wrong, so your answer (with a more complex concept doesn't) really help :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this (as pointed out in the comments by dmahapatro) is for use with a REST API.

It makes no sense in the context of displaying this directly to an end-user. However, in the context of a REST API used by another system or by AJAX calls from within a HTML/GSP page it makes a lot of sense.

Since a REST API can be based on HTTP requests made to send/receive JSON data, having the configuration on how a domain class is represented in JSON as a part of the domain class itself helps keep things centralized and tidy. Instead of JSON being manually created or configuration for representing your domain classes in JSON kept somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as I answered dmahapatro, I still can't get the "REST API" architecture meaning, I thought that it means simply using the methods PUT POST DELETE ... but after reading several docs it seems that I was wrong, so your answer (with a more complex concept doesn't) really help :/ can you give a better explanation or maybe an example please?

Comment: I've added a bit more, but not understanding how JSON plays in a REST API isn't going to be something that can be explained without explaining what a REST API is. That falls outside the scope of the question/answer.

Comment: You can also add that the 'utility' of JSON views in grails is so you can modify what data gets rendered into JSON. That is useful when you are either adding extra data in (that isn't part of the domain) or excluding some data. Also useful to changing the structure of the JSON.